# Fetching a BehaviorSubject value and updating it in a component updates the cached data which is read in another component

Tags: angular, caching, observable, behaviorsubject

I am using two components and a shared service to share data between these two components. The code in the component1.ts and shared service app-shared.service.ts is shown below.

component1.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.appSharedService.getAllCars()
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.cars = response;
      this.appSharedService.updateCarsList(this.cars);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

app-shared.service.ts

```
export class AppSharedService {
carsSubject : BehaviorSubject<Car[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Car[]>([]);
cars: Observable<Car[]>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
}
getAllCars (): Observable<Car[]> {
if (!this.cars) {
    this.cars = this.http.get<Car[]>(this.apiUri, this.headers)
    .pipe(
        map( response => response),
        publishReplay(1),
        refCount()         
    );
  }
   return this.cars;
}

 updateCarsList(cars : Car[]) : void{
    this.carsSubject.next(cars);
 }
}
```

I am calling the getAllCars() method from component1 and caching the value inside the service and then updating the carsSubject value by calling this.appSharedService.updateCarsList(this.cars) from the component 1. Now I navigate to a second component component2.ts and read this updated carsSubject value and modify it inside the component as shown below.

component2.ts

```
updateCarsList() {
  this.cars = this.appSharedService.carsSubject.value;
  for(let i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
    if(this.cars[i].id === car.id) {
       this.cars[i] = car;
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

The cached value is getting updated with the this.cars value in component 2 and now on navigating to component 1, the new value is displayed. I don't understand why the cached value is getting updated. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Because JavaScript passes **references** to objects by value. It doesn't pass **objects** by value. I.e. no copy of the array and of its cars is made anywhere, so both components have a reference to the same array, containing the same cars. Like if you shared the address of a google docs document with two people: if one writes on it, the other one will see the modifications.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes I understand that if I am reading from carsSubject value in both the components but here I am trying to assign it to a local variable inside component 2 and the cached variable in service is not pointing to this

Comment: And both variables reference the same array. Here's some basic code illustrating what you have in a simpler way: `const a = [{foo: 'bar'}]; const b = a; b[0].foo = 'baz'; console.log(a[0].foo);` This will print "baz", because a and b are two local variables referencing the same array.